# Give unique class to last item in view

Tags: views, theming

**UPDATE:** I now see that drupal has a built in setting you can check to add even/odd,first, and last classes to the items in the view. Is there a way I can append another class to the last item using this?

---

For responsive purposes I was planning on adding the bootstrap .hidden-lg class to the last item in a view. This is in order to display more items when I go from a 3 column to a 2 column view. I did see that there was a style output template for views that iterates through each of the rows (as you can see below) but I wasn't sure how to take advantage of that.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Default simple view template to display a list of rows.
 *
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */
?>
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Unless the only option is to perform some regex on the last item of the foreach statement.

As a heads up, I'm already outputting the content and applying custom classes using a view field output template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try next code snippet

```
/**
 * @file
 * Default simple view template to display a list of rows.
 *
 * @ingroup views_templates
*/
end($rows);
$last = key($rows);
?>
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
<?php if ($id == $last): ?>
    <?php $classes_array[$id] .= ' last-element'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```